# paperclip private files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, paperclip

Is there a way to make paperclip attachments private? As in only where I explicitly want a user to be able to access a file, can the user access the file.

Obviously the file can't be in a public directory, but how do I get paperclip to check the user's access rights when trying to access that file to begin with?

Comment: What are you using for authentication and/or authorization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PaperClip does not handle downloading the attachment.
It only handles the uploading, processing and saving of the file.

If you need something like this, you must save the photo in a private folder (or in DB, if this suits your needs). Then, you can implement a controller/action that will verify the user's credentials, read the file and then send the file as binary content.

To send a binary content from the controller, you may want to check [ActionController::Streaming API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#M000422)

You may also want to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57104/rails-binary-stream-support) on SO.

Comment: The only thing is, paperclip also allows for serving of those files, such a thing would have to be disabled.

Comment: No. It's just that paperclips default setting for storing the files is in the applications public folder.

Comment: This method will set the uploaded file to private and show you how to create an expiring link to it: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3