# How to represent / persist information for a table which will contain a dynamic set of configurations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
create table app (id, name, desc)
create table app_config (id, app_id, key, value)
```

For each row in app there could be many rows in app_config (e.g. could be 3 or 5 rows and the value could be of different types - string, text, date ..)

What would be the best strategy to render this dynamic view or persist this information via Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different possibilities depending on the your usage. Here are some of them:

1. You want to store the configuration as a hash of key and value pairs, each key can only be once there. The whole configuration is modified and stored at once.

   ==> You could use a Ruby hash, and store it as one object as a binary (see ["Rails Binary"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57104/rails-binary-stream-support)) or you could store it as (YAML) text.

   Your database migration for the `AppConfig` could be:

   ```
   def change
     create_table :app_configs do |t|
       t.text :config
       t.integer :app_id
       t.timestamps
     end
   end
   ```

   This is the solution to store it as YAML text.
2. You could store each entry in your app_config as a separate object. Then you have a 1:many relation between the `App` and its `AppConfigs`. You have to care about that for each key, only one value can be stored. Perhaps you have to ensure that at least 3 `AppConfig` objects are created for each `App`, and some could be added optionally.

   Your model should then be:

   ```
   class App < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :app_configs
     ...
   end
   class AppConfig < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :app
     ...
   end
   ```

Depending on what you want to do, how to modify the configuration, and how to store it, one of the solution will be better suited for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

open your console and create a test project:

```
$ rails new testproject
$ rails generate scaffold App name:string description:string
$ rails generate scaffold AppConfig key:string value:string app:references
$ rake db:migrate
```

See the generated files and study its code.

Open your model files and add your validation rules.

One strategy for your problem could be listing all app and in each row add a link to a app_config list. You may use nested routes and you will have links like: /app/12/app_configs

So, open your routes.rb, delete the routes added by scaffolding and type:

```
resources :apps do
  resources :app_configs
end
```

After saving the file, type on your console:

$ rake routes

In order to see your new resteful routing helpers, edit your new scaffolding views and controller and change your links to use these new ones.

When in app_conf, you should set and get AppConf with app_id = request[:app_id] in AppConfs controller.

Next time you post a question lake this, try to tell us what you have thought as possible solutions. It will help us to understand better your concerns and will increase the probability for a good reply.